# Find 2 continuous functions $F$ and $G$ defined on $[a;b]$, such that $F'(x) = G'(x)$, but $F(x) - G(x) \neq \text{const}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

> **The problem**: Find 2 continuous functions $F$ and $G$ defined on $[a;b]$, such that for every $[\alpha;\beta] \subset [a;b]$ there exists an interval $[\alpha';\beta'] \subset [\alpha;\beta]$, where $G'(x) = F'(x)$, but $F(x)-G(x) \neq \text{const.}$

**What I tried/Questions**:

I believe that from the $[\alpha;\beta]$ conditions I can deduce that the functions must have derivatives but $F(x)-G(x) \neq \text{const}$ at every point of $[a,b]$, but this already doesn't make sense to me, like, how can $F(x)-G(x) \neq \text{const}$ at a point? But even if I consider $[x,x]$ for example not to be a valid interval and have a rule that an interval must have at least two points, this also doesn't work because for every two points I take there exists a point that lies between them and it still "converges" to a single point. The fact that the functions have to be continuous makes the task seem impossible. I also considered having multivariable functions continuous against $x$ but discontinuous everywhere against $y$. However, the problem is worded in such a way, that $F$ and $G$ must be functions of only $x$. I feel very lost, any hints will be appreciated!

Here's the problem, it's in russian so sorry about that: [image]

Comment: What you say "but $\;F-G\neq$ constant *at every point of* $\;[a,b]\;$" cannot be possible if $\;F'=G'\;$ in some open interval...

Comment: Have you seen the Cantor function?

Comment: do you need the functions F,G to have the property that for every interval there is a subinterval where F,G are everywhere differentiable?

Comment: @Joanpemo "Not equal to a constant at every point" is nonsensical to start with.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you. Yes, indeed. What I meant is that if $\;F'=G'\;$ on some interval, then $\;F-G=k=$ a constant on that interval.

Comment: $F(x)-G(x) \neq const$ at every point of $[a;b]$ was something I wrongly inferred from the problem statement, I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I think the problem should be restated and say $F'(x)=G'(x)$ almost surely otherwise there no such $2$ functions.

Comment: @waterfalls But then **what is** the problem statement *exactly* ??

Comment: @Joanpemo it says that the function F-G is not a constant function

Comment: @clark Oh, I see...then Cantor function works alright, otherwise as you wrote it it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Let $F$ be the Cantor function, $G\equiv 0.$

Comment: Thank you! I believe that's it, very cool looking function!

Comment: No, nevermind, I thought about it some more and it doesn't seem to fit the problem. For example, I can take the $[1/3; 2/3]$ interval in the Cantor function $(F(x))$, the value of $F(x)$ there is $1/2$, the value of $G = 0$ and on $[1/3;2/3]$ the function $F(x)-G(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Perhaps if take F to be the Cantor function, graph it, then take the longest interval of constant value, so $[1/3;2/3]$ in the first iteration, and put in the Cantor function on that interval there instead, defined for $[1/3;2/3]$ instead of $[0;1]$. Then we move the main function up, so that it remains continuous at $x = 2/3$. Then we find the next longest interval and repeat the process. However, will doing this infinitely many times mean that we get some regular function and the derivative is not 0 anymore? I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear on the algorithm, I hope I got the point across.

Comment: Let's be precise here. You want an example such that for every $[\alpha,\beta] \subset [a,b]$ there exists $[\alpha',\beta'] \subset [\alpha,\beta] $ such that $F'=G'$ on $[\alpha',\beta']$ and $F-G$ is not constant. Right? Now, where exactly is $F-G$ supposed to be nonconstant then? On $[\alpha',\beta']?$ That's not possible. So what did you mean?

Comment: I updated the post with the screenshot of the problem from the book (it's in Russian), once again, sorry for the confusion. I agree that the way I worded it makes such a function not possible, but I just translated the problem statement word for word. Which makes me think that there might be inaccuracies in the book itself. I will ask our lecturer for clarification when I get the chance. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I believe the author meant that $F-G$ is not constant on $[a,b].$